# Python JSON file not printing

Tags: python, json, printing, pycharm

So I have been attempting to develop an app, which also included JSON being used. Below is a snippet from it, however, it is not printing, but says process finished with exit code 0.

```
import json

import item as item

with open('test.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

if (["userdata"], ["openedbefore"]) == 1:
    print("Application has been open before")



f.close()
```

This is the JSON file:

```
{
    "userdata" :[
      {
        "openedbefore": "1",
        "username": "Test"
      }
    ]
}
```

I am a bit new to Python, so apologies if the issue is very direct.
Thanks in advance! I have also tried replacing the if statement with:

```
if data['userdata']['openedbefore'] == '1':
    print("Application has been open before")
```

that produces this error:
if data['userdata']['openedbefore'] == '1':
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: You're comparing a tuple with two lists in it with a string each to `1`. Those will never be equal. What are you actually trying to test?!

Comment: `data['userdata']['openedbefore'] == '1'`?

Comment: I was trying to check that if the "openedbefore" was equal to 1, then print.

Comment: I used this code, "data['userdata']['openedbefore'] == '1'", however it shows this error: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Answer (score 1):

When you load json, it will become a python dict. So you need to access it by :

```
data["userdata"]["openedbefore"]
```

It's just like accessing nested arrays tho. So, the basic format is like this:

```
json_dict["child1"]["childofchild1"]["childof_childofchild1"]...
```

Then, the `userdata` has a square bracket that indicates an array, so you need to access its index. Thus, your `if` statement should be:

```
if data["userdata"][0]["openedbefore"] == 1:
```

Comment: Doing this produces this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
    if data['userdata']['openedbefore'] == '1':
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: if data ["userdata"][0]["openedbefore"] == "1":